# how to put multiple plotmeans on one plot

Tags: r

I have following data:

```
x = structure(list(y1 = c(107.372719264016, 118.863299513623, 122.162515227, 
111.233227509519, 92.1059066900521, 92.5830204386651, 94.5195626032137, 
104.412959061795, 91.3601725324563, 109.253785952959, 178.771878945058, 
144.951255075154, 155.596668292633, 174.961110441768, 120.832044563506, 
136.643512128174, 135.187051040663, 180.285899983425, 158.394853261036, 
159.408612698416, 210.922565904703, 200.637214897327, 212.170348364241, 
189.17609660446, 196.488287848291, 190.289086295862, 209.437584230891, 
213.663792465693, 212.051141677785, 178.19577259738), gp = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), y2 = c(23.4346699162695, 23.5659769309565, 
25.6831595647438, 26.2750453870631, 27.4124437247719, 26.6151271841002, 
18.3542500476327, 25.6479059225537, 22.7590841129755, 28.3977047665418, 
49.5381487676808, 52.6323571458394, 52.0978945491726, 47.9337311261507, 
40.2061776362212, 59.8929725029682, 55.0611040997365, 54.3854566071441, 
45.3167212599129, 49.4203766938382, 65.3710290649776, 83.0698942827895, 
89.5332774858779, 71.9625027199287, 85.8762119093763, 69.1433238492174, 
84.390713674473, 83.6843406930946, 75.1866926526086, 80.4928087390204
)), .Names = c("y1", "gp", "y2"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
> 
> head(x)
         y1 gp       y2
1 107.37272  1 23.43467
2 118.86330  1 23.56598
3 122.16252  1 25.68316
4 111.23323  1 26.27505
5  92.10591  1 27.41244
6  92.58302  1 26.61513
> 

> 
> plotmeans(x$y1~x$gp)
> plotmeans(x$y2~x$gp)
```

I want to plot means of 2 columns by same group column on one plot. I can make 2 plots but how can I put them both on one plot? I do not want par(mfrow..) function but want both graphs on same plot with same y-axis. 'plotmeans' function is in gplots package. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what package is `plotmeans` ?

Comment: It is from gplots packages. I will edit in question also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can do something like:

```
plotmeans(x$y1~x$gp,ylim=c(0,220))
plotmeans(x$y2~x$gp,add=TRUE)
```

which would return a warning (that you can ignore) because the `add=TRUE` parameter gets passed to both `plot()` (which doesn't use it) and `plotCI()` (which does use it). In the specific case of your data, you get additional warnings because the confidence intervals are too small to plot properly - you can get round this by plotting on a log scale, or with a smaller y range if either make sense for your data - neither of which look particularly good to me:

```
#Smaller y range
plotmeans(x$y1~x$gp,ylim=c(60,120))
plotmeans(x$y2~x$gp,add=TRUE)

#log scale
plotmeans(x$y1~x$gp,ylim=c(20,220),log='y')
plotmeans(x$y2~x$gp,add=TRUE)
```

If neither of these is satisfactory, you could try plotting to a 2000x2000 pixel device - eg

```
    png("file.png",2000,2000) 
    plotmeans(x$y1~x$gp,ylim=c(0,220))
    plotmeans(x$y2~x$gp,add=TRUE)
    dev.off()
```

which is big enough to display the error bars correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. The error bars will probably become all right with larger data. On the png file, the labels on axes are really very small. Is it possible to change from CI to std error for error bars?

Comment: You can play around with the settings described in `par()` such as `cex.axis` and `cex.lab` and then the margins to get bigger axis labels on the png, but this would be a faff.

I don't know of any way to use the plotmeans function to plot std errors - I'd look at `plotCI()` in the `plotrix` package to see if that might be useful, but you'll need to calculate the errors first, then pass them to the plotting fuction.